# Oracle 12 limits

Tags: oracle

I'm newbie on Oracle and I want to know the following limitations on Oracle 12 :

1. Maximum Database Size
2. Maximum Table Size
3. Maximum Row Size
4. Maximum Rows per Table
5. Maximum Columns per Table
6. Maximum Indexes per Table

Currently I found these limitations

1. Maximum Database Size = 8000T
2. Maximum Table Size
3. Maximum Row Size
4. Maximum Rows per Table = Unlimited
5. Maximum Columns per Table = 1000
6. Maximum Indexes per Table = Unlimited

Thank you for your help

Comment: Database limits are divided into four categories: `Datatype Limits` `Physical Database Limits` `Logical Database Limits` `Process and Runtime Limits` see: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-ED26F826-DB40-433F-9C2C-8C63A46A3BFE.htm#REFRN004

Comment: How do you get *Maximum Database Size = 8000T*? One Bigfile Tablespaces can be up to 128 TiB (for Blocksize of 32ki) but the database may contain 64ki Tablespaces, i.e. 8 EiB (Exbi Byte) or app. 8'000'000 TiB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All this information is in the docs:

Physical limits:

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-939CB455-783E-458A-A2E8-81172B990FE9.htm

Logical limits:

https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/REFRN/logical-database-limits.htm

Maximum row size:

> For Oracle8, Release 8.0 and later, the answer is 4,000GB (or 4GB per
>   LOB, 1,000 LOBs per table). Just take the maximum varchar2 size (4000)
>   or char size (2000) and add them up—4000x1000=4,000,000 bytes of
>   structured data.

Comment: I know these documents but I do not know how to interpret them for my needs

Comment: What do you need?

Comment: For example, how calculate the maximum Table Size ?

Comment: There is not limit for that, same thing for the row size, the limit can be the maximum tablespace size if the table is not partitionned (32 TB for a 8K blocksize tablespace or more if you increase the blocksize or partition the table). But why do you ask thoses questions?

Comment: Because I'm comparing the limits of Postgres, Mysql and Oracle and I found these limits for Postgres : Maximum Database Size Unlimited
Maximum Table Size 32 TB
Maximum Row Size 1.6 TB
Maximum Field Size 1 GB
Maximum Rows per Table Unlimited
Maximum Columns per Table 250 - 1600 depending on column types
Maximum Indexes per Table Unlimited

And I want to known the values for these limits for Oracle

Comment: Maximum ROW SIZE: 
For Oracle8, Release 8.0 and later, the answer is 4,000GB (or 4GB per LOB, 1,000 LOBs per table). Just take the maximum varchar2 size (4000) or char size (2000) and add them up—4000x1000=4,000,000 bytes of structured data.

Comment: And for others limits ?

Comment: No table size limit to my knowledge. For the database size you got it wrong like mentionned by  @Wernfried Domscheit. the other are mentionned in the link posted in the answer.